# Interactive legend in Visiblox chart

Tags: c#, wpf, visiblox

I have a Visiblox chart showing several `LineSeries`. I would like to be able to show/hide these individually, preferably by clicking on the corresponding `LegendItem` or inserting a checkbox in the legend item.

I tried adding a checkbox to the `LegendItem` ControlTemplate, and it does show up, but I can't manipulate it in any way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retemplating the LegendItem is the way to do this - we've just published a blog post describing how to achieve exactly what you've described (and more): http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2012/04/interacting-with-the-legend.

Comment: I actually solved it by creating a separate legend, which also made the layout better, but since my use case is static with regards to number and types of plots, my solution will not work in general.